# vbHow to get javascript value in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

How to get javascript value in asp.net?

I am using vb asp.net, javascript and html

When user click on 'pay' button in html code, than I will to run some code in javascript, than pass TokenHF.value in asp.net

issue is that: inside page_load() function, test TokenHF.value will be alway empty.
this is bc of on load function. any idea how to get TokenHF.value in asp.net?

vb asp.net code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim test = TokenHF.value
end sub
```

html code:

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="TokenHF" runat="server"></asp:hiddenfield>
<div id="card-number-element class="field"></div>
<div id="card-expiry-element" class="field"></div>
<div id="card-cvc-element" class="field"></div>
<input id="postal-code" name="postal_code" class="field" placeholder="90124" />
<button type="submit">pay</button>
```

javascript code:

```
<script>
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_982wyfu9sfdsf');
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    function setOutcome(result) {
        if(result.token){
            document.getElementById('<%= TokenHF.ClientID %>').value = result.token.id;
        }
    }

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var options = { address_zip: document.getElementbyID('postal-code).value,
        };
        stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement, options).then(setOutCome);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: you are not make any post back - so the input control post their data back

Comment: no, need to do this without form

Comment: what if i create session in javascript and get session value in asp.net?